# Prove that if there are two different paths between vertices $x$ and $y$ in a simple graph,then there must be a cycle in the graph.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that if there are two different paths between vertices $x$ and $y$ in a simple graph,then there must be a cycle in the graph.

-It seems simple enough that if there are two paths in a simple graph there would be a cycle although I have no clue as to how to prove this, let alone which proof strategy to use. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not true if it is a directed graph (where the edges have directions).  What is a "simple" graph?

Comment: Assuming an undirected graph: What if you just trace the route from $x$ to $y$ on the first path, and then the reverse route on the second path?

Comment: A simple graph is defined in our book as having no loops or multiple edges.
Our problem said nothing about the edges being directed so i can only assume you can either way. I think I was mistaken because I assumed you could cycle through using loops. But from the definition of a simple graph there are no loops allowed, so I am a bit lost on how to proceed.

Comment: I suspect you mean that a simple graph has "no edges from a node to the same node, and at most one edge between any two nodes." Nontrivial graphs of course will have more than one edge.  I think your book defines a "loop" as an edge from a node to itself.

Comment: Edited my above comment in reply to it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. So that would mean that having a graph with two vertices and two edges, both of which connect the two vertices would be a cycle. I just don't understand exactly how we would turn this into a proof. It almost seems like common sense, unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30384/discussion-between-michael-and-d-peterson).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be vertices such that two distinct paths $P_1$ and $P_2$ join $x$ to $y$ such that $P_1$ is of minimal length. (i.e. if two vertices $x'$, $y'$ are connected by two paths then these paths must be at least as long as $P_1$)

If $P_1$ meets $P_2$ at a vertex $z$ not equal to $x$ or $y$ then we obtain shorter paths $P_1'$ and $P_2'$ joining $x$ to $z$, where $P_1'$ is shorter than $P_1$ which is a contradiction.

Therefore, the path $P_1\overline{P_2}$ (so follow $P_1$, then $P_2$ backwards), is a cycle in the graph